# Same width for every letters in an input

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have an input which is styled to make it look like there is 5 inputs. It only accepts letters ([a-z])

[image]

What I would like to do is give the 5 letters in that input the same width so that every letter is centered in its to prevent things like this

[image]

This is the CSS for this input for now

```
input {
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: 1.18em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 0.55em;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 6em;
}

input::after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-left: .55em;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a fixed-width font?

Comment: I guess I could, I didn't know it existed. What fixed-width font do you suggest ? It has to work on iOS and Android.

Comment: courier, arial-mono etc. should work

Comment: I went for courier. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in a comment by @HeikoRupp, use a fixed-width font. But do not use Courier, since it’s about the worst choice, and in older systems it might even be a bitmap font (so that looks tolerable in a few font sizes only). In practice, in modern Windows systems, the name Courier refers to Courier New (unless the system really has Courier installed), which is somewhat better, but questionable.

Partly based on a [font survey](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-Monospace.shtml), I would suggest the following:

```
input { font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Lucida Console, monospace }
```

The generic name `monospace` means that the system’s default monospace font will be used. On Android, this means Droid Mono, the only monospace font available by default.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this plugin: https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js

```
lettering();
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/krMhR/

Comment: This is based on jQuery and I'm already using Sencha Touch so I' would be to heavy. But good to know though